# What is a joystick-style tub faucet handle called?

Tags: shower, faucet, bathtub

My tub has a knob:

[image: shower tub faucet knob view 1]
[image: shower tub faucet knob view 2]

Twisting it clockwise or counter-clockwise changes the temperature, and pulling it out from the wall controls how strong the flow is.

It is *not* very ergonomic, especially when slippery from soap.

My kitchen sink faucet, on the other hand, has a very easy-to-use handle:

[image: kitchen faucet]

I can control the power and temperature without even using my hands (just by knocking it with my elbow, if I wanted to). I love how simple and user-friendly that is.

I want to replace my tub faucet knob with an ADA-compliant joystick-style handle, but I'm not sure what search terms to use.

I've been having trouble filtering results on Amazon, Home Depot, etc.

P.S. "Single Handle Valve" isn't a specific enough search term. I want to know how to filter to only results where the lever controls temperature and flow independently. I don't like the kind where Hot is only available at full power.

Comment: I think you would need to replace the entire valve, not just the handle.  The existing tub knob only controls temperature, not flow rate, both of which your "joystick" does.  What I think you may want is a "single handle faucet" but it may depend whether you have a shower head as well as the faucet.  What do you have?

Comment: The replacement of a shower knob with a handle is common and fairly easy. Please post a pic of what you actually have. Your description sounds like an early Moen, however it could be a delta or others.  A pic or pics that show where the positioning of the mounting screws are on the trim plate will give us an indication of what brand of valve you have.  Then we can give better recommendations.  Or take off the knob and take it to a plumbing supply store. They should be able to help you.

Comment: Pictures of your actual device are always better than random images from the internet. Nobody will judge you for a dirty tub... Basically, though, as @Huesmann said, you're looking at replacing the whole thing with a new single handle faucet. I don't think _any_ are sold these days with the old-school "ball handle" - they've all got lever handles. "Lever handle" might get you some better search results, but maybe not.

Comment: @FreeMan they may not be "ball handle" style, but there still are plenty of valves that only control temperature—not flow—like that.

Comment: IIRC, recent Moens (OK, less recent by now) come with a lever handle but they will send you a ball handle if you ask them to. Since I despise the ball handles I've never taken them up on it.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Plumbing/comments/lsnyce/replacing_delta_faucet_acrylic_ball_with_a_lever/ ... https://www.lowes.com/pd/Danco-Chrome-Lever-Shower-Handle/1000296529 "    Designed to replace the original manufacturer Delta handle for you bathroom lavatory faucet. Compatible with the Delta #70 and #212 ball lavatory faucets and will work with the older Delta #600 series shower and tub/shower faucets. One-handle ergonomic design adjusts the water temperature and volume with ease" Or replace the valve which most modern **mixing valves** come with one.

Comment: @FreeMan I added photos above. Thanks!

Comment: @Huesmann I'm not sure what you mean about my knob. I control the flow rate by pulling the knob out from the wall. I control the temperature by twisting it. See new photos above. Thanks!

Comment: @Huesmann I meant to also answer your question: yes, I have a shower head too (not shown). Thanks!

Comment: I'm with you 100%, @Ryan! That's why we've installed a 2-handle faucet in our brand new shower. I also like to be able to have independent control of temp & pressure and I despise those single handle faucets. The Europeans have more "modern" looking controllers like this, but they're quite pricey here in the US. America seems to have more-or-less abandoned the concept...

Comment: @Ryan ah, I didn't know you had the pull available—my shower knob is rotate only, for temperature.  Only one pressure is allowed.  So basically you're looking to find a valve you can operate with your elbow?

Comment: @Huesmann Correct. I don't like when controls require too much finesse and dexterity, especially in slippery situations. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/283934/what-is-a-joystick-style-tub-faucet-handle-called#comment592207_283949 might be on the right track.

Comment: Note to self: I don't know why this is so hard to remember , but when the knob feels loose, I should use a thin blade (e.g. pocket knife) to slip in between the silvery part and the clear part, not the black circle part. Then a Philips screwdriver to tighten. https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipM0tKsDY9pPIJ-0wfCkdGY2SQP-yQn3ULtAV8_s

Answer (score 6):

A lever handle, or it may also be marketed as a handicap accessible handle. Check with your shower controls manufacturer to see what they offer.

Image search on your actual valve image reveals it to be a Moen. Evidently a 1225 cartridge and TL473 trim would get you where you want to be per the site linked in comment which came up from the image search.

Comment: Evidently a Moen, and updated cartridge kits are available with lever handle: https://terrylove.com/forums/index.php?threads/updating-an-old-moen-shower-valve-with-pictures-tl473-or-tl470.76710/

Comment: Wow, what a great find! Thanks! That does look just like my photo. https://amzn.to/3Qf2NpA Does therefore seem like it would work. Given its title, I wondered whether the search term "Single Handle Valve" would be helpful. Nope., because its results include non-joystick options (such as ones where you can't control flow independent of temperature). This will get me on the right track, though. Thanks!

Comment: If you look at @Ecnerwal 's link you can see that this only replaces the handle.  You will have to pull it out to turn it on and rotate for temperature.  The "joystick" style you mentioned would require a new rough in valve, cartridge and trim.

Comment: @Ukko What does "would require a new rough in valve, cartridge and trim" mean? And is there a type of hardware that is _better_ than what Ecnerwal linked to that also allows independent control of flow and temperature? Thanks!

Comment: @Ryan what is linked above will only get you a handle in place of the ball.  It will not operate like most lever handles, it will work exactly like the ball does now.  The cartridge is the inside valve part that mixes the water newer ones automatically adjust for pressure changes or temperature changes.  Those are all larger in diameter than what you have now and will require a new rough-in valve which is the part soldered to the pipes in your wall.  You can then make that look however you want by using different trim kits to get the color and shape you want.

Comment: Given that the described issue was with the ball being hard to grasp, a new cartridge and handle that work the same as the old with a better handle should solve the OP's problem *without* ripping the wall apart. The new cartridge will almost always make it easier to operate than a 40 year old one...

Answer (score 3):

These knobs that pull directly out of the wall are hard to operate.  You cannot convert them to lever-style just by changing the knob.  If you want to make it easier without replacing the entire shower valve (a relatively large job) you can:

1. Wrap the knob in heat-shrink rubber tubing that will make it easier to grip
2. Install a flow control valve on your shower head.  It can control flow finely and *is much easier to operate*.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What is the brand of your faucet? Different companies have different canisters (internal mechanism inside of the faucet that control the water flows) and they are often not compatible with each other.

if your tub handle doesn't have a brand name... Turn off your water, take the handle apart, place all of the pieces together, and take it to your local plumbing/hardware store, they will have what you need or know where you can get it.

Answer (score 1):

They are called "single lever tub and shower valves".

Sometimes you might see "with diverter" for the tub valve part.